# avoiding /accounts/login/?next in django

Tags: python, django

**urls.py**

```
#...
from myapp.views import MyView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


urlpatterns = [
    #....
    url(r'^terminator/', login_required(MyView.as_view()), name='sexy')
    
]
```

**views.py**

```
class MyView(View):
    
    
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'itworks.html')
```

I am accessing `MyView` class via `Somelogin` class which redirects to "terminator url". But the problem is: django redirects me to following url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/terminator`.

Of course, this address is not defined and gives me 404.

I played with `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in settings, but this just brings more confusion to code. So is there anyway to avoid this "default/next" in django and just go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/terminator`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to define `LOGIN_URL` in your `settings.py`. That will override the default URL of accounts/login.

Add to your settings:

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

Before:

```
http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/?next=/password/reset
```

After:

```
http://localhost:8000/login?next=/password/reset
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid it by going to admin and logging in there,so that you wont be redirected.
I resolved this issue by adding:
`url(r'^accounts/',include(admin.site.urls))`
in urls.py file.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxJntqOYv3g , the cause of this error comes from an unlogged user trying to access some part of the application that requires a logged in user. So this will not happen if you are logged in some registered account.